# What is the best data structure to store ranges for fast queries?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, intervals

I have this situation where I have *N* timelines each containing blocks. The blocks contain tokens with a specific index and know their maximum and minimum token indexes. There's also an index mapping blocks' first indexes to a (timeline, block) pair. Here is an example:

```
Timeline 1: [1 2 5 8 9 11] [14 17 18 21] [22 23 25 26] ...
Timeline 2: [3 4 6 7 10 12] [13 15 16 19 20 24] [27 28 34 45] ...

Index:
  1 -> timeline 1, block 1
  3 -> timeline 2, block 1
  13 -> timeline 2, block 2
  14 -> timeline 1, block 2
  22 -> timeline 1, block 3
  27 -> timeline 2, block 3
```

As you can see, there's no missing token (no gap).

Those data structures are what I have initially. **What would be the best alternative data structure to optimize queries of a specific token index?** Say I want to retrieve token 19. Now what I have to do is: a dichotomic search in the index to find the good blocks for each timeline, and then a full search within each block. With token 19, the dichotomic search would result in blocks (1, 2) and (2, 2) which can contain 19, and then do a full linear search to find token 19 (no dichotomic search within blocks is possible here since tokens have various sizes and are not contained in any data structure yet).

Thank you!

**Edit**: I'm thinking about using an interval tree containing intervals of all the timelines. The problem is that a query would still result in many intervals. Plus, it doesn't optimize too much compared to binary searches.

Comment: What is expected result, when querying the data? For example, the query is 19 - what is the result? Is it the timeline number, block and position in block?

Comment: @Draco: Exactly. A block is a big blob and the only way to seek to the nth token within it is to start from the first one and read sequentially.

Comment: @eepp Can't you move the indices of tokens in a block at the beginning of the block? If you need to search for a specific value, like '\0' to know when a token ends, it could work, and it would reduce the search to only one of the N timelines

Comment: @eepp Also some data about what are the numbers here could be relevant: N, the number of blocks, the total size of the tokens? A proper optimization would depend on this information

Comment: You may want to take a look at the Interval Trees explanation in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHyGlha7bjE)

Answer (score 0):

You could have an array *A* of *t* pointers to objects that hold a pointer to the token, its timeline, and block. If you can hold references in an array using whatever mechanism your language likes.. I'm not sure what you can do if you can't binary search inside blocks.

Comment: I cannot keep as many references as there are tokens in a data structure (like an array) since there's way too many tokens. The problem would be easy to solve if I had just a few tokens.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to my mind (if it does not take a lot of memory space) is to create an array of blob values, where index is your query token (19 - in your example) and the value is the blob part that corresponds to it. Array should be good, as you don't have gaps. Constructing this array is O(n) and searching there is O(1). But this will bring some benefits only if amount of queries is relatively big, as the existing structure is also good optimized already. (Should actually do testing here, which way is quicker.)

Constructing array:

```
array = []
foreach ( timeline in timelines ){
  foreach ( block in timeline){
    foreach( token in block ){
      array[token.index] = token.value
    }
  }    
}
```

If that is too costly, try saving only timeline number for the token. This way you will not have to search every timeline, when the query comes. All you will have to do is to take the timeline, binary search a block, and plain forward search inside a block.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a sparse space filling curve? When you have the index it's a function that's reduce the dimension. A space filling curve is the same but it's also adds a spatial information to the index. Another data structure for a space filling curve or a spatial index is a quadtree. Hence you can use a quadtree or a kd-tree to search.